# How to parse bash array using Python shlex?

Tags: python, arrays, bash, lexical-analysis, shlex

#### Input:

```
declare -a ForwardPort=([0]="L *:9102:10.0.1.8:9100 # remote laptop" [1]="L *:9166:8.8.8.8:9100 # google")
```

#### Desired output

And I would like to get this output:

```
{
    'ForwardPort': [ 
        '"L *:9102:10.0.1.8:9100 # remote laptop"', 
        '"L *:9166:8.8.8.8:9100 # google"'
        ]
}
```

#### Attempt

I tried to play a bit with `shlex`, but the parsing of the array is terrible:

```
import shlex
line='ForwardPort=([0]="L *:9102:10.0.1.8:9100 # remote laptop" [1]="L *:9166:8.8.8.8:9100 # google")'
lex=shlex.shlex(line)
list(lex)
['ForwardPort', '=', '(', '[', '0', ']', '=', '"L *:9102:10.0.1.8:9100 # remote laptop"', '[', '1', ']', '=', '"L *:9166:8.8.8.8:9100 # google"', ')']
```

#### Question

Is there a way to automatically parse the value of `ForwardPort` into a list?

N.B.: Don't reproduce at home it was a bad design decision that lead to this convoluted problem :S

Comment: Where are you getting the `ForwardPort` from? It seems like you are traversing two different languages. Is there any reason why your `ForwardPort' is in bash array format?

Comment: `shlex.shlex` is a lexer, it will return a list of tokens which is up to you to parse,

Comment: ...moreover, `shlex` was defined for POSIX sh. bash isn't that.

Comment: If you're only going to parse single line strings, use regex, if you need something with context/multiline parsing I suggest pyparsing

Comment: @VivekAkupatni `ForwardPort` come from a bash script that contains variables

Comment: Taking a step backwards, what's generating that input? Why can't it generate something more useful for Python (or any other language) to work with?

Comment: project scope evolved from a small CLI tool to a web application using Docker. Input will migrate to a better format like JSON is future release.

Comment: Is there a separate file that can be sourced from bash that contains only the values you want, or a mechanism to tell the script to stop executing before taking any actions? If so, you could launch a bash interpreter from Python that sources the file and emits its contents in an easier-to-parse format.

Comment: ...actually, is the script public? There's a good chance I could *come up with* a way to stop it after the configuration is set, if I could see it. (There's a lot that can be done with exported functions).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the code is open source https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/blob/master/daemon/template

Comment: Oh -- so there's no side-effecting execution at all! That's actually perfect; you could run `subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', '''source "$1" && printf '%s\0' "${ForwardPort[@]}"''', '_', configFileNameHere], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\0')[:-1]` and there you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could print that out in bash with:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a ForwardPort=([0]="L *:9102:10.0.1.8:9100 # remote laptop" [1]="L *:9166:8.8.8.8:9100 # google")
res=$(python -c 'import json, sys; print(json.dumps({"ForwardPort": [v for v in sys.argv[1:]]}))' "${ForwardPort[@]}")
echo "$res"
```

gives:

```
{"ForwardPort": ["L *:9102:10.0.1.8:9100 # remote laptop", "L *:9166:8.8.8.8:9100 # google"]}
```

---

if you have that bash array definition as string in python, you could try this somewhat crude parsing:

```
import re

line='ForwardPort=([0]="L *:9102:10.0.1.8:9100 # remote laptop" [1]="L *:9166:8.8.8.8:9100 # google")'

name, arr = line.split('=(')
arr = arr[:-1]  # removing the trailing ')'
lst = [item for item in re.split('\[\d+\]=', arr) if item]

dct = {name: lst}
print(dct)
```

Comment: BTW, the usual way I serialize a bash array for Python to parse is with NUL delimiters: `printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}"`, and then your Python code can just split on the NULs. But like this answer, that depends on actually invoking bash to do the work.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I'm loading the bash from a Python context

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez: tried to parse that within python. is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Python, and launching bash from there (effectively as the inverse of [the answer by hiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817784/14122), which launches Python from bash):

```
import subprocess

print_array_script=r'''
source "$1" || exit
declare -n arrayToPrint=$2 || exit
printf '%s\0' "${arrayToPrint[@]}"
'''

def bashArrayFromConfigFile(scriptName, arrayName):
    return subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', print_array_script, '_', scriptName, arrayName],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\0')[:-1]

print(bashArrayFromConfigFile('file.txt', 'ForwardPort'))
```

Tested with an input file created as follows:

```
cat >file.txt <<'EOF'
declare -a ForwardPort=([0]="L *:9102:10.0.1.8:9100 # remote laptop"
                        [1]="L *:9166:8.8.8.8:9100  # google")
EOF
```

...properly emits as output:

```
['L *:9102:10.0.1.8:9100 # remote laptop', 'L *:9166:8.8.8.8:9100  # google']
```